# Create picture from geocordinates

Tags: c#, google-maps, gps, openstreetmap

I have the geocordinates of a trip and I would like to save the picture that display the path on a map.
Do you know an api or library that woud do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Static Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) for that. The Google Static Maps API lets you embed a Google Maps image on your web page.From there, you can draw your path.